# Does typescript have auto-properties yet?

Tags: typescript

I've head that in typescript, properties can be defined the way the are in C# with auto setter and getter. Although I haven't been able to implement properties this way as the intellisense says no such syntax is supported by typescript, I couldn't find any proper example for implementing auto-properties either. All I could find about this suggested declaring methods with `get` and `set` modifiers next to them which is by no means similar to anything in C# or even automatic. So is there any auto-properties in typescript?

Comment: I have to ask - Why not just use a property? JS isn't like C#, it's not a breaking change to switch to getters / setters later if you need to. `class A { b: string }` then `const a = new A(); a.b`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, TypeScript does not support C#-like auto properties. You have to declare getters and setters with your the usual JS syntax.

While there has been [proposals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7628) for [auto-properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8858) support, none have been accepted. The gist is that this [detracts from trying to move TS towards where JS should be](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7628#issuecomment-199674194), and is unlikely to ever be supported.

Answer (score 5):

Type in VSCode **prop** and press the "Tab" key.

Property will be generated:

```
export class Person
{
    private _name: string;
    public get Name(): string
    {
        return this._name;
    }
    public set Name(v: string)
    {
        this._name = v;
    }
}
```